# How to print out the digits of an integer of any length?

Tags: variables, printing, integer, out, digits

This program is works as long as the divide variable is of the same base 10 power as the variable num, in this case the number is 12345 so divide needs to be 10000. While this works for 5 digit numbers, anything with more or less than 5 digits will not have their individual digits printed out. How do I configure divide to have be of the same base 10 power as num automatically?

```
public class lab5testing
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int num = 12345, digit = 0, divide = 10000;
        if (num != 0)
        {
            while(num != 0 )
            {
            digit = ((num/divide)%10);
            System.out.println(digit);
            divide /= 10;
            if (divide == 0)
            {
                num = 0;
            }               
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(num);
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try with this :

```
int length = (int)(Math.log10(num)+1);
```

and then :

```
int divide = Math.pow(10,lengh);
```

Comment: I get an error saying: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int.

Comment: strange...how about this : int length = String.valueOf(num).length();